# How can I tell if my graphics card is dying or if my drivers are incorrect?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, crash

I have a Sapphire Radeon 6870HD GPU. When I was doing some non-intensive stuff on my PC earlier today it crashed, and whenever it boots it:

- Goes through the windows spash screen
- Displays the 'welcome' with a bunch of horizontal artifacts
- Hangs at either a lightblue or just black screen. No error messages or BSODs

I have already tried switching to the onboard graphics, which had no such problem.

Now that I know something is wrong in the GPU department, how can I determine wether its' the drivers or the hardware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Artifacts means 99% failing hardware, so unfortunately your best bet is to get a new GPU. If you have someone, who will borrow you another GPU you can try that. Or if you want to be 100% sure your GPU is bad, try putting it into someone else computer. Also, when GPU is failing, the last resort is "baking the graphic card". As crazy as it sounds, it works, just google it. Results will vary - I baked few cards in my lifetime, and as far as I can tell, "baked" card will typically work from 1 month to year... or you know, it will not work at all.

Comment: Something i forgot to mention: I do not get any artifacts on Bios or the windows loading screen, and whenever i boot into safemode (which is also artifact-free) and I disable the graphics card device in device management, the problem is gone.

Comment: Then your best option is still trying that card in other computer. Seriously, I was reparing computers for half of my life, and if some piece of hardware is not working on 2 stations, it means it is bad. If by any chance it is working correctly on other PC, then you should start looking for driver issue - in most cases, you just have to use older drivers, best option is to use ones that were shipped with the card on CD, if possible. The golden rule of PC repairs is ruling things one by one - don't try to look for solution on every front. Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same GPU and ran in the same problems as you but i was using Windows 10.

If you are using the AMD lastest drivers (Crimson Edition 16.2.1 Beta), try switching on the old catalyst one (15.7.1), i personally had alot of problems with Crimson Edition drivers.

If its still not working, i suggest using [Display Driver Uninstaller](http://www.guru3d.com/files-details/display-driver-uninstaller-download.html) in safe mode to remove all traces of others video drivers, then install drivers version 15.7.1, [available here for windows 7](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=legacy3&os=Windows%207%20-%2064)... That step fixed the artifacts problems for me.

Comment: I tried your input, but with the same result. I am afraid mr/mrs LeBaux is correct...

Comment: Unfortunetaly, if removing all drivers and reinstalling didn't work, it's probably the case.

Comment: Well, too bad. Thanks for the help all the same!